# How to validate non-empty field using Mongodb validator

Tags: mongodb, validation

I have a collection with schema:

```
{
  "name": "Jhon",
  "lname": "Doe",
  "status": "Accepted"
}
```

I want to add a validation to this collection, such that, whenever any new document is being added in it, the `status` field of that document should not be empty.

I tried using `$jsonSchema` validator:

```js
db.createCollection("users", {
    validator: {
       $jsonSchema: {
          bsonType: "object",
          required: [ "name", "status"],
          properties: {
            name: {
                bsonType: "string"
             },
             lname: {
                bsonType:  "string" 
             },
             status: {
                bsonType:  "string" 
             }
          }
       }
    }
 })
```

But, this schema accepts document:

```js
db.users.insert({'name':'abc','status':''})
```

How do I validate that the `status` field is not empty using mongodb validator?

Comment: `minLength` is an option for JSON Schema. MongoDB implements a subset of the available options but not all ( links `$ref` and `$schema` are an obvious omission for what should be obvious reasons ). You can see all the supported options and a basic description of their usage in the [`$jsonSchema`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema/#json-schema) documentation.

Comment: You might also note that *Validators* in MongoDB are really just query expressions. The documentation makes heavy example usage of `$jsonSchema`, but this is not ***required***, as in fact ANY valid query expression will do.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks for your help. I tried using `minLength`. It works fine, but it accepts strings containing empty spaces as well. And for my use-case, I only need strings containing alphabets. Hence, I specified `regular expression` using `pattern`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.
I used **Regular Expression**.

```js
db.createCollection("users", {
    validator: {
       $jsonSchema: {
          bsonType: "object",
          required: [ "name", "status"],
          properties: {
            name: {
                bsonType: "string"
             },
             lname: {
                bsonType:  "string" 
             },
             status: {
                bsonType:  "string",
                pattern : "^[A-Za-z]+$", 
             }
          }
       }
    }
 })
```

Comment: For less strict validation use `.+` RegExp pattern (any symbol at least once)